# Error when executing SQL statement in python

Tags: python, sqlite

The following code gives me an error:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT gsr, {} FROM {} WHERE session_id=?".format(column,table),(id))
```

where `column` and `table` are strings and `id` is a number. I'm getting a ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type error.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Why don't you use `"SELECT gsr, {} FROM {} WHERE session_id={}".format(column,table, id)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `(` an `)` arround id :

```
db = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT gsr, {} FROM {} WHERE session_id=?".format(column,table),id)
```

You want use an int `id` to set `?` not a tuple `(id)`

or use named placeholders :

```
db = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT gsr, {} FROM {} WHERE session_id=:id".format(column,table),{"id":id})
```